# Why does the Wikipedia article on "sex offender" list "sexting" as a crime?

Tags: sexual-assault

> Some of the crimes which usually result in a mandatory sex-offender classification are: a second prostitution conviction, ***sending or receiving obscene content in the form of SMS text messages (sexting)***

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_offender

Wait... How is "sexting" a "sex crime" or "sex offense"? Is it implying that it's done to a minor? Has the article been vandalized?

Comment: https://www.aclu.org/blog/juvenile-justice/minnesota-prosecutor-charges-sexting-teenage-girl-child-pornography

Comment: https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/legal-issues/mds-top-court-upholds-child-pornography-charge-against-teen-who-texted-friends-a-video-of-herself/2019/08/28/95cd6ba6-822c-11e9-95a9-e2c830afe24f_story.html

Comment: https://www.huffpost.com/entry/teens-child-pornography-sexting_n_5d6ff6d1e4b09bbc9ef8f108

Comment: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-teens-sexting/in-some-states-sexting-could-land-teens-in-jail-for-a-long-time-idUSKCN1RS2BT

Comment: https://www.criminaldefenselawyer.com/crime-penalties/juvenile/sexting.htm

Answer (score 5):

### Because in some jurisdictions it is

While sexting underage subjects is pretty much a crime universally, sexting of anyone is illegal in many jurisdictions, For example, in most countries that follow Sharia law.